# How to pass and change index of array in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have the gist of how to do this, but I'm a beginner in vue, and I'm struggling with how to put it together. I need Control.vue to update the index in Exhibitor.vue. I know I'll have an $emit event happening in Control when I click on the button to pass the index data to the parent, and I'd have to use props to pass data from Exhibitor to its children, but how? I can't understand how to pass the index of an array with my code.

**Exhibitor.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="exhibitor">
  <section class="exhibitor_info">
    <h1 class="exhibitor_name">{{ exhibitors[index].firstName }} {{ exhibitors[index].lastName }}</h1>
    <h2>Tag Number: {{ exhibitors[index].tagNum }} <em>{{ exhibitors[index].species }}</em></h2>
  </section>
  <div class="frame"><img :src="getImgUrl(exhibitors[index].picture)" alt="Exhibitor-Picture" class="image"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Exhibitor',
  data() {
    return {
    exhibitors: [],
    index: 0
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.fetchExhibitors();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchExhibitors() {
      let uri = 'http://localhost:8081/exhibitor'
      this.axios.get(uri).then(response => {
        this.exhibitors = response.data
      })
    },
    getImgUrl: function(pic) {
      return require('../assets/' + pic)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Display.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="display">
    <exhibitor></exhibitor>
    <buyer></buyer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Exhibitor from './Exhibitor.vue';
import Buyer from './Buyer.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    'exhibitor': Exhibitor,
    'buyer': Buyer
  }
}
</script>
```

**Control.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="control">
    <display></display>
      <button v-on:click="incrementLeft">Left</button>
      <button v-on:click="incrementRight">Right</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Exhibitor from './Exhibitor.vue';
import Display from './Display.vue';
export default{
  props: ['exhibitors', 'buyers', 'index'],
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    incrementRight: function() {
      // Note that '%' operator in JS is remainder and NOT modulo
      this.index = ++this.index % this.exhibitors.length
    },
    incrementLeft: function() {
      // Note that '%' operator in JS is remainder and NOT modulo
      if (this.index === 0) {
        this.index = this.exhibitors.length - 1
      } else {
        this.index = --this.index % this.exhibitors.length
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    'display': Display
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hang on, Control.vue is your parent and has Display.vue as a child, which in turn has Exhibitor.vue and Buyer.vue as it's children. I don't see why you need display at all. Import exhibitor and buyer direct into control, and you could even have your exhibitors array in control and pass them to the child as a slot.

Comment: Hey @Andrew1325, Control.vue is a child of Exhibitor and Buyer. It's main purpose is to control which element exhibitor and buyer is showing in the array. I need Display.vue for the purpose of this project to display different layouts of the information.

Comment: The normal way to do this is to use props.  Have you tried making index of prop of Exhibitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can get what you want to happen and there are two ways of making it happen that I can think of. First I will just clarify the terms relating to this because you seem to have them the wrong way around. Let's look at you tier structure which is like this:

```
Control.vue
  contains: Display.vue
    contains: Exhibitors.vue & Buyers.vue.
```

Therefore Control.vue is the parent of Display.vue which is the parent of Buyers.vue and Exhibitors.vue.

Anyway, What we need to do is control the array of exhibitors (and I guess buyers but you didn't include them in your code so I'll do likewise) which is in Exhibitors.vue from Control.Vue even though they don't have a direct parent child relationship. What I've done is set a prop that is passed to Display.vue which uses scoped slots to render the exhibitors from Exhibitors.Vue. Because the left and right buttons need to know when to stop going I have emitted the array length from Exhibitors.vue to Display.vue and again to Control.vue. It all works so heres some code.

```
//Control.vue
<template>
    <div class="content">
        <display v-on:finalLength="setIndexLimit" :i="index"></display>
        <button @click="changeDown">Down</button>
        <button @click="changeUp">Up</button>
        <p>{{indLimit}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Display from '@/components/Display'
export default {
    components: {
        Display
    },
    data: () => ({
        index: 0,
        indLimit: 0
    }),
    methods: {
        changeUp() {
            if (this.indLimit === this.index+1) {
                this.index=0
            }
            else {
                this.index ++
            }
        },
        changeDown() {
            if (this.index === 0) {
                this.index = this.indLimit - 1
            }
            else {
                this.index --
            }
        },
        setIndexLimit(e) {
            this.indLimit = e
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and

```
//Display.vue
<template>
  <div id="display">
      <p>From Display</p>
    <exhibitors v-on:ExLength="setLength">
        <p>{{i}}</p>
    </exhibitors>
    <exhibitors>
        <p slot-scope="{ exhibitors }">{{exhibitors[i].firstName}}</p>
    </exhibitors>
    <exhibitors>    
        <p slot-scope="{ exhibitors }">{{exhibitors[i].lastName}}</p>
    </exhibitors>
    <exhibitors> 
        <p slot-scope="{ exhibitors }">{{exhibitors[i].tagNum}}</p>
    </exhibitors>
    <exhibitors>     
        <p slot-scope="{ exhibitors }">{{exhibitors[i].species}}</p>
    </exhibitors>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from '@/components/admin/Exhibitors'

export default {
  components: {
    Exhibitors
  }, 
  props: [
      'i'
  ],
  data: () => ({
      exhibitLength: null
  }),
  methods: {
      setLength(e) {
          this.exhibitLength = e
          this.$emit('finalLength',e)
      }
  }

}
</script>
```

And finally:

```
//Exhibitors.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :exhibitors="exhibitors"><p>I'm the child component!</p></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    exhibitors: [
            {
                firstName: 'Joe',
                lastName: 'Burns',
                tagNum: 1,
                species: 'ant'
            },
            {
                firstName: 'Tom',
                lastName: 'Yorke',
                tagNum: 2,
                species: 'bee'
            },
            {
                firstName: 'Flit',
                lastName: 'Argmeno',
                tagNum: 3,
                species: 'giraffe'
            }
        ],
  }),
  mounted: function () {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
        let length = this.exhibitors.length
        this.$emit('ExLength', length)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

So as I said all that works, you can click the buttons and it will loop through the array contents. You can style it how you want wherever you like. However, it is a bit messy with props and slots and emits and whatnot just to relay a single index number and it would be far easier in my opinion to have a **vuex store** where 'index' is stored as a state item and can be used and changed anywhere without all the above carry on.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying! I have the code working where it goes through the array, but it won't loop because the exhibitor length isn't being emitted from the Exhibitor.vue where it's mounted. I've tried emitting through a function, but that didn't pass a value at all. In Exhibitor.vue, the length defaults to 0.

Comment: Hmm, I ran all this code and it worked fine. Maybe check for typos in the functions that are supposed to emit. And put a console.log(length) in the mounted function and another console log in the methods that receive the emitted value to see if we can find where it breaks down.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely the first function where it's mounted.
let length = this.exhibitors.length console.log(length)
and length equals 0.

Comment: It may be that the mounted function runs before your `fetchExhibitors()` method has returned the result so the exhibitors array is still empty. If you put the `let length = this.exhibitors.length this.$emit('ExLength', length)` at the end of fetchExhibitors method, after `this.exhibitors = response.data`, it should work.

Comment: Hey Andrew, everything is working fine, but there are error messages in the console that say:

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: exhibitors[_vm.i] is undefined"

found in

---> <Exhibitor> at src/components/Exhibitor.vue
       <Display> at src/components/Display.vue
         <Control> at src/components/Control.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>

It definitely has something to do with the array, but I'm not sure why it would be undefined when it shows up and is loaded.

Comment: It would have to do with the vue lifecycle. Initially exhibitors is an empty array and you are filling it with an API call in your fetchExhibitors method. An axios call is asynchronous meaning that it makes the call and gets the data back a little later. So I would think that vue reaches the render stage of its lifecycle before the axios call has returned the data to populate 'exhibitors', hence it it 'undefined'. Are you still calling `fetchExhibitors()` from created? And in that method why do you call this.axios.get? I'd think axios.get only would be better.

Comment: Then where would I make the call to fetch the exhibitors? When I make call to just axios.get, it says that axios is undefined